# How to add attribute manage options image in magento 2.2.7

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, magento2.2.7

I have created the manage option attribute for product attributes. description,image and use_in_guide ina Manage Option section. I able to save the image, description but image data value is not captured in table eav_attribute_option table.

the file name is option.php

```
protected function _prepareUserDefinedAttributeOptionValues($option, $inputType, $defaultValues)
{
    $optionId = $option->getId();

    $value['checked'] = in_array($optionId, $defaultValues) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
    $value['intype'] = $inputType;
    $value['id'] = $optionId;
    $value['sort_order'] = $option->getSortOrder();
    $value['description'] = $option->getDescription();
    $value['image'] = $option->getImage();
    $value['filter'] = $option->getUseInGuide();

    foreach ($this->getStores() as $store) {
        $storeId = $store->getId();
        $storeValues = $this->getStoreOptionValues($storeId);
        $value['store' . $storeId] = isset(
            $storeValues[$optionId]
        ) ? $this->escapeHtml(
            $storeValues[$optionId]
        ) : '';
    }

    return [$value];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer myself, I have overridden the container.phtml
and added the below-mentioned script and calling controller via ajax uploaded file in the directory.

```
$('body').on('change', '.inputFile', function(e) {
    var option = this.name.split("[")[1].split("]")[0];
    var fileName = e.target.files[0].name;


    var myFormData = new FormData(); 
    myFormData.append('option_image', e.target.files[0]);

    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl(); ?>callfilter",
        type: "POST",
        data: myFormData,
        contentType: false, 
        cache: false,
        processData:false, 
        success: function(result){
            $('#option_image_'+option).val(result.path);
        }           
    });
});
```